# How to locate element having dynamic ids?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html-table, automation, cypress

I want to locate this element:

```
<tr class=" category-2 saleproductname  " id="21" xpath="1">
<input class="check-box" id="BillInfo_4__isSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" xpath="1">
```

I am trying to locate the id, but the id is dynamic, this particular item can have id="BillInfo_0__isSelected, sometimes id="BillInfo_1__isSelected and I have to keep on changing them on code. Is there any solution to this? Here only the id = 21 is unique but unable to use this as well. I am trying to use id since the class is common and locates other elements too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `id="21"` is unique, query for that and use `.find()` (which will find within the parent) to access the input

```js
cy.get('tr#21')
  .find('input')
```

In case there's several inputs in the same row

```js
cy.get('tr#21')
  .children()
  .eq(0)          // first child element
```

If `id="21"` changes per build, it would be a good idea to add a `data-cy` attribute

```html
<input class="check-box" id="BillInfo_4__isSelected" data-cy="my-input" ... />
```

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="my-input"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to find an element that:

1. Starts with **BillInfo_**. `[class^=""]`
2. Ends with **__isSelected**.  `[class$=""]`

```js
const element = document.querySelector('[id^="BillInfo_"][id$="__isSelected"]');

console.log(element);
```

```html
<div id="BillInfo_4__isSelected"></div>
```